# Why does ψ^2 ( square of orbital wave function ψ) give the probability of an electron in a given region?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory, electrons, atomic-structure

Today I was introduced to the Orbital Wave Function for electrons. 
$\Psi$ is a mathematical function for coordinate of electrons and has no physical meaning.
But $\Psi^2$ gives probability of an electron.
How does a function for coordinate give probability distribution when squared ? How is the $\Psi$ working ?

Please explain me in easier to understand terms with out monster equations.

Comment: What's the monstrous equation (Schrödinger's equations)? And state of the particle is completely described by $\Psi$, it got it's meaning.. doesn't $\Psi^2$ gives probability density?

Comment: Discussed here in the question and answers: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/194999

Comment: @Zenix yes! I don't really understand it. I suppose it relates the various energies of the particle with its coordinates. Am I right?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/92244/what-is-the-difference-between-%cf%88-%cf%88%c2%b2-radial-probability-and-radial-distribut

Comment: "Today I was introduced to the Orbital Wave Function" - well that suggests that you already know more then you really need on your level of education, and teacher didn't tell you how it work for good reasons.

Comment: @Mithoron Yes that might be true but I have some basic knowledge about it and it's graphs and how to find nodes and all ! But why am I getting down votes? Is there anything wrong?

Comment: Not much, but it's modulus of function squared and, well, comments about monster functions are better... in comments not in body of question. Also I feel this may be too broad.

Comment: Please don't go in depth Navoneel, you don't really need to know more about than this, if you are preparing for competitive examinations. You can't grasp these things in 10+1 grade... little knowledge is always harmful. Remain focused on goal and have faith in your faculties. Rest depends on you, I will upvote so that you don't get demotivated.

Comment: This is the Born interpretation and it is a postulate about how quantum mechanics works. As far as we can tell, it's right. There is no easier way in quantum mechanics. You either look at the equations and get some insight, or you don't.

Comment: Well,this depends.. Do you know the basic postulates of quantum mechanics,especially the 3rd one regarding eigenvalues and eigenvectors?(You should obviously know the Hermitian operators postulate and the normalization one)

Comment: Ok thanks to everyone in the comments! I realise I'll learn this when am eligible (i.e. in higher grade)